# CSS variable does not change when the result is derived from other css variables

Tags: css, css-variables

My guess is this a browser issue!

But its **interesting**

Below I have 2 variation of calculating height and assigning it.

The **Black box** is using css variable and to calculate and assign the height of the box.

```
:root {
--content-height: calc(var(--app-height) - var(--app-footer) - var(--app-footer));  
}
.black {
  height: var(--content-height);
}
```

The **Blue box** is assigned height without using css variable and it works, while the black doesn't work

```
.blue {
    height: calc(var(--app-height) - var(--app-footer) - var(--app-footer))
}
```

**Guess both will work in same way?** NO

https://codepen.io/Anenth/pen/VVwpzp

Only the **second** one works fine! Checkout the below code

```js
document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--app-height', "100px")
```

```css
:root {
  --app-header: 20px;
  --app-footer: 20px;
  --app-height: 300px;
  --content-height: calc(var(--app-height) - var(--app-footer) - var(--app-footer));
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.box-with-calc-var {
  height: var(--content-height);
}

.box-without-calc-var {
  background: #00F;
  height: calc(var(--app-height) - var(--app-footer) - var(--app-footer));
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-with-calc-var"></div>
<div class="box box-without-calc-var"></div>
```

Comment: both are working fines  ... but differently

Comment: as a side note, the first code you described is totally different from the snippet you provided ... if the `--content-height` was really defined at the same level of your element, both will work the same : https://jsfiddle.net/8xfrdv62/

Comment: @TemaniAfif check this https://codepen.io/Anenth/pen/VVwpzp

Comment: the codepen is like the snippet your provided here ... the variable `--content-height` is defined a root level but if you check your explanation before the snippet where you defined `.black`, you defined the variable there at the same level of height definition which is different from defining at root level (like explained in the duplicate and like shown in the fiddle I shared)

Comment: Understood, But how does changing the scope change the calculated value?

Comment: you read the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, Interesting

Comment: and did you find the explanation you want ?

Comment: It's little confusing why it behaves like this

Comment: simply don't see it as a programming languge but as CSS ...The value at root level is evaluated at root level and will not change if you change the variable again on an inner level ... it's all about Cascading : From top to bottom. Variable at root level don't see the one in the body

Comment: @TemaniAfif that makes lots of sense! thanks